# epsilon delta for limits of complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Show that  $$\lim_{z->2i} 2x+iy^2=4i$$
Prove this using epsilon-delta proof.

I've tried like this  but got stuck in middle: $f(z)=2x+iy^2$

$$|f(z)-4i|=|2x+iy^2-4i| \le |2x|+|y^2-4|
                      =2|x|+|y-2||y+2|$$

How to choose delta?

Comment: The best way would to express the function in terms of things that go to zero (ie $x$ and $y-2$): $2x + i((y-2)+2)^2 = 2x + i((y-2)^2 + 4(y-2)+4)$ (and then $f(z) - 4 = 2x + i((y-2)^2 +4(y-2))$